# In react redux app: Issue mobile screen resetting (jump) on every set state or change state

Tags: reactjs, redux

Using handleChange to submit textfield value. When I entered text in the field, the screen reset or jump again to the default view.

Comment: not getting by your sentence ,add jsx code to get it clear

Comment: Can you please add your code?

Comment: Fixed!
By removing inner scroll from the content (child component).
Issue: whenever the state sets the screen jump.

Comment: Thanks Shmili and Kishan for asking.